# How to get users job title using pnp-sp-js Sharepoint 2019 on-premise

Tags: spfx, modern-experience, 2019, react, pnpjs

I am working with SharePoint on-premise 2019 and I am trying to get job title from multiple users that are stored in a list as an object.

I am using pnp-sp-js and React framework and can successfully get users ID from a list and then users data with pnp-sp-js siteUsers but jobTitle is missing. What is the other way to get users job title or am I doing something wrong?

```
let tempData = await pnp.sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle(this.props.list)
      .items.getAll();
    console.log(tempData);
    
    let users = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
      users[i] = await pnp.sp.web.siteUsers.select("jobTitle").getById(tempData[i].userId).get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the jobTitle from the AD with the help of LoginName and `getUserProfilePropertyFor`. LoginName property was received with this line:

`users[i] = await pnp.sp.web.siteUsers.getById(tempData[i].UserId).get();`

and the anwser (jobTitle is stored in property named `SPS-JobTitle`):

```
 for (let i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
      let a = await pnp.sp.profiles.getUserProfilePropertyFor(
        users[i].LoginName,
        "SPS-JobTitle"
      );
      temp_jobTitle[i] = a;
    }
    console.log(temp_jobTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Job Title of user using SharePoint REST API like:

```
<site url>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List Name')/items?$select=Title,Author/JobTitle&$expand=Author
```

Where `Author` is internal name of Person or Group field. You can get the internal name of any of your list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Similarly you can expand the person or group field using SP PnP JS and select the Job Title of user, like:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";

const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List Name").items.select("Title", "Author/JobTitle").expand("Author").get();
console.log(items);
```